# Equilibrium Solubility of CO2 in Aqueous Solution and its Dependence on H3O+ Concentration

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, aqueous-solution, solubility, concentration

The equilibrium solubility of $\ce{CO2}$ in an aqueous solution is given by three chemical reactions:
$$
\begin{align}
\ce{CO2(g) &<=> CO2(aq)}\label{rxn:R1}\tag{R1}\\
\ce{CO2(aq) + H2O &<=> H2CO3(aq)}\label{rxn:R2}\tag{R2}\\
\ce{H2CO3(aq) + H2O &<=> HCO3-(aq) + H3O+(aq)}\label{rxn:R3}\tag{R3}
\end{align}
$$
Considering a system $E_1$ at equilibrium with constant pressure and variable volume, an increase in the concentration of $\ce{H3O+}$ would shift the equilibrium towards $\ce{CO2(g)}$ and consequently result in a change in volume. Let's denote the new system with the altered equilibrium as $E_2$.
The law of mass action for each reaction is defined as:

$$
K_1 = \frac{\ce{[CO2(aq)]}}{\ce{[CO2(g)]}},\
K_2 = \frac{\ce{[H2CO3(aq)]}}{\ce{[CO2(aq)]}},\
K_3 = \frac{\ce{[HCO3-(aq)][H3O+(aq)]}}{\ce{[H2CO3(aq)]}}
$$

Since $K_1$ is constant at a given temperature, and $\ce{[CO2(g)]}$ remains constant because the pressure is assumed to be constant, $\ce{[CO2(aq)]}$ is also constant. With the same argument, the concentration of $\ce{H2CO3(aq)}$ should be constant. However, the concentration of $\ce{HCO3-(aq)}$ in $E_2$ needs to be lower than in $E_1$ because the concentration of $\ce{H3O+}$ is higher in $E_2$, and $K_3$ is a constant. Therefore, the change in volume can be fully explained by the alteration in the concentration of $\ce{HCO3-(aq)}$.

Does that make sense? It seems quite strange to me that there is no change in concentration for the reactants in $\mathrm{R1}$ and $\mathrm{R2}$

Comment: Concentrations of a given molecular entity must be the same in all equations, as it is the same system. // Be aware MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q Titles.

Comment: Add the equations or multiply the $K$'s, then as $\ce{H_3O^+}$ goes up $\ce{HCO_3^-}$ goes down because each $K$ is constant and so is $\ce{CO_2(g)}$.

Comment: @porphyrin Hello porphyrin. I was thinking the same but then I got the following. Lets sum them all and "magically" put some protons there so that the $\mathrm{pH}$ goes down. Then, $\ce{HCO3-}$ must go down. But it can only go down with the generation of $\ce{CO2(g)}$ (so the global reaction actually goes to the left), but $\ce{CO2(g)}$ is constant. What am I thinking wrong?

Answer (score 2):

General solution of such systems is solving a set of $N$ nonlinear equations for $N$ variables.

There are concenctrations of $\ce{H+}$, $\ce{OH-}$, $\ce{CO2(aq)}$, $\ce{H2CO3(aq)}$, $\ce{HCO3-(aq)}$, $\ce{CO3^2-(aq)}$ + $p_{\ce{CO2}}$, i.e. $N=7$.

- There is 1 equation for total $\ce{CO2}$ inventory
- There is 1 equation for charge neutrality.
- There are equilibrium equations:

  - 1 equation for $\ce{CO2}$ dissolution
  - 1 equation for $\ce{H2CO3}$ formation
  - 2 equations for $\ce{H2CO3}$ dissociation
  - 1 equation for water auto-ionization

So 7 variables and 7 independent equations.

With constant $\ce{CO2(g)}$ partial pressure, it can be simplified as $[\ce{CO2(aq)}]$  and $[\ce{H2CO3(aq)}]$ would be at equilibrium constant as well.

Exact solving of the equation set often lead to a cubic or more complicated equation for $[\ce{H+}]$. It may be impossible or challenging to resolve analytically.

But can be solved numerically e.g. by the MS Excel solver package, e.g. by minimalization of function:

$$z = \sum_{i=1}^N{\text{(EqLeftSide}_i - \text{EqRightSide}_i)^2}$$

The practical hint: Use for variables and parameters single-letter symbols, common in algebra, for easier manipulation.

Another way is simplification by evaluation of eventual strong inequalities.

E.g.
$$[\ce{HCO3-}] \gg [\ce{CO3^2-}] \implies [\ce{HCO3-}] + [\ce{CO3^2-}] \simeq [\ce{HCO3-}]$$

or

$$|x| \ll 1 \implies \frac{1}{1 \pm x} \simeq 1 \mp x$$

Such simplifications often lead to exact solutions, e.g. a quadratic equation, of an inexact, simplified task.